# Invoking a program from command shell from SQL CLR

Tags: c#, sql-server, process, sqlclr

I'm invoking a CLR from SQL to prepare data for ingestion via BULK INSERT.  One of the things I need to be able to do is unzip a file.  First, I'm just trying simple stuff ... copying a file.  Can't even get that to work.

For example:

```
string command = "/C COPY /Y err.txt y.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);
```

returns error "System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed."

So that's a little too complicated, I guess. So I try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
```

I get the same error message, even though I haven't done anything yet, except create a process that I'm even invoking.  I have the assembly set to EXTERNAL_ACCESS on the SQL side.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you set the `PERMISSION_SET` to `SAFE` or `UNSAFE`? `SAFE` is default. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345106.aspx

Comment: I tried PERMISSION_SET SAFE as well. It also produces a problem.

Comment: SAFE is the default. Try Unsafe.

Comment: That worked! It's the opposite of what I thought it needed to be. Thanks!

Comment: And that fixed not just the copy, but the invocation of the gzip command, as well! Thanks!